# How do you open the Minimap in Crazy Craft 3.0?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

How do you open the minimap in Crazy Craft? I have tried the "M" button, but it didn't work!

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [mod list](http://test.voidswrath.com/modpacks/crazy-craft-3-0/) for Crazy Craft 3.0, there doesn't seem to be any mod included that adds a minimap. Therefore I'm willing to assume that there is no minimap mod (such as Rei's Minimap) installed, and thus pressing <kbd>M</kbd> will not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

my answer is that you should change the controls for the minimap to work so when you see the mini map is not working look in your controls settings and change the the letters to make it work

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! I'm not quite sure what you mean by this answer, could you elaborate a bit? You may want to consider fleshing out you answer anyway, as there is already a good answer for this question.